# Enable/disable droppable based on ul length

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have a droppable jqueryui element:

```
    // droppable group
    $group.droppable({
        accept: "#batch > li",
        activeClass: "ui-state-highlight",
        drop: function( event, ui ) {
            moveToGroup( ui.draggable );
        }
    });
```

Based on the length of ul list inside group, it should be disabled or not.

```
        if ($('#group ul li').length >= N_GROUP)
            $group.droppable("disable");
        else
            $group.droppable("enable");
```

Where should I put this condition? I put it in the moveToGroup function, but realize that it's not working because: once group is disabled, it can't call moveToGroup and can't be enabled again. Which event should this code respond to?

Answer (score 0):

You might consider running your logic on the `dragstart` event instead of within `moveToGroup()`. That way the droppable will be disabled if it is too full while the user is dragging. Then, you would re-enable the droppable on the `dragend` event.